# boost; regular expression negating string

Tags: regex, boost

I need to write a regex to negate a string given a string:

```
&SomeString/*SomeOtherString
```

I want to match `/*` only if there is no `&` followed by string of any length. I wrote `(?!&[[:word:]]+)/\*` but it does seem to work. Could you help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Boost does not support a variabel width negative lookbehind. Use a 2-step check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new boost::regex backtrack control verbs for this.
(*since version 1.61*)

`(?:&.*?/\*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|/\*)`

Expanded

```
 (?:
      & .*? /\* (*SKIP)(*FAIL)
   |  /\* 
 )
```

For finer detail, change the `.*?` to words or something specific to *theString*.

---

If using version below 1.61, just match the offender and check later.
If capture group 1 matched, then its not it, otherwise it is it
*smatch[0].c_str()*

```
 (?:
      ( & .*? /\* )                 # (1)
   |  /\* 
 )
```

Comment: @Mariano - `(*SKIP)` is never reached without matching `&.*?/\*` perhaps you're thinking of something else.

Comment: I was referring to matching the text `&SomeString/*SomeOther/*String`. However, that's not defined by the OP, so it was only intended as a comment.

Comment: It matches &SomeString/*SomeOther`/*`String only. I don't know what the OP's context is but it's not a skip/fail issue. Far as I read from it, he wants to match `/*` only. If he want's to match all up to there that's a different issue.

Comment: It is a very good anwer and I upvoted it. Allow me to reword it as I meant it: Since the OP didn't fully specify the criteria for the match,  do take into account that if one expects the regex to always fail even if there are more occurences of `/*` in the string, then `(*COMMIT)` could be used ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/uL6pV7/1)). This would also be more efficient as it prevents further match attempts.

Comment: @Mariano - Yeah, I understand what you mean. Used in a global match, `(*COMMIT)(*FAIL)` will terminate matching because the current position can't get past that point and commit won't let it bump the position. The affect in this case however, using `(?:&.*?/\*(*COMMIT)(*FAIL)|/\*)` will match all occurrences of `/*` before the commit is encountered. The OP seems farther away from needing that outcome.